# How to replace everything after a specific character in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

Hi I wanted to replace everything in a specific DataFrame Column. Say I am looking at a particular website that uses parameter urls and wanted to remove them to get cleaner data.

`urls = {'url':['https://www.adidas.com/us/grid=true', 'https://www.adidas.com/us/boxinggrid=true', 'https://www.adidas.com/us/yoga?grid=true', 'https://www.adidas.com/us/women-sale?price=price']}`

`urls = pd.DataFrame(urls)`

I want to remove the question marks and everything afterwards in this dataframe. Is there a regular expression I can use that will allow me to remove everything? I know I can just remove the question mark with the below code, but that isn't super helpful.

`urls['url'].str.replace('?','',inplace=True)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
urls['url']=urls.url.str.split('?').str[0]



                                      url
0        https://www.adidas.com/us/grid=true
1  https://www.adidas.com/us/boxinggrid=true
2             https://www.adidas.com/us/yoga
3       https://www.adidas.com/us/women-sale
```

Comment: Happy did assist